# Rule transformation between letter and number

Tags: string-manipulation

I have a global rule as follow:

```
transformRules =
 {a1 -> Subscript[Style["a", Italic], 1], 
  b1 -> Subscript[Style["b", Italic], 1], 
  c1 -> Subscript[Style["c", Italic], 1],
  d1 -> Subscript[Style["d", Italic], 1], 
  e1 -> Subscript[Style["e", Italic], 1], 
  f1 -> Subscript[Style["f", Italic], 1],
  a2 -> Subscript[Style["a", Italic], 2], 
  b2 -> Subscript[Style["b", Italic], 2], 
  c2 -> Subscript[Style["c", Italic], 2],
  d2 -> Subscript[Style["d", Italic], 2], 
  e2 -> Subscript[Style["e", Italic], 2], 
  f2 -> Subscript[Style["f", Italic], 2],
  A1 -> Subscript[Style["A", Italic], 1], 
  B1 -> Subscript[Style["B", Italic], 1],
  C1 -> Subscript[Style["C", Italic], 1], 
  D1 -> Subscript[Style["D", Italic], 1],
  E1 -> Subscript[Style["E", Italic], 1], 
  F1 -> Subscript[Style["F", Italic], 1],
  A2 -> Subscript[Style["A", Italic], 2], 
  B2 -> Subscript[Style["B", Italic], 2],
  C2 -> Subscript[Style["C", Italic], 2], 
  D2 -> Subscript[Style["D", Italic], 2],
  E2 -> Subscript[Style["E", Italic], 2], 
  F2 -> Subscript[Style["F", Italic], 2]};
```

It is tedious to write them one-by-one. So I write a function to transform then automatically.

Thanks  for **Kuba**'s hints

<strike>transform=
      # -> Subscript[Style[#1, Italic], #2] & @@ StringSplit[ToString[#], ""] &</strike>

```
transformRules =
 Function[
  {symbol},
   symbol ->
    Subscript[Style[#1, Italic], #2] & @@ StringSplit[ToString[symbol], ""]]

transformRules =
  transform /@ 
   {a1, b1, c1, d1, f1, a2, b2, c2, d2, e2, f2, A1, B1, C1, D1, E1, F1}
```

> [image]

However, my auxiliary function `transform` cannot apply the following cases:

```
transform[AA1]
transform[AB12]
```

And I also know that the main problem is `StringSplit[ToString[#], ""]`

#### Question

This my first time to use the **string function**, and I search teh *DOC* about `StringSplit`. However, I cannot solve it.

- How to split the string acoording the number?

For example,

`A1-> {"A","1"}, AB1-> {"AB","1"}, AB12-> {"AB","12"},ABC12-> {"ABC","12"}`

Comment: @Kuba, Yes, I make a mistake, I need the style `_Symbol->Subscript[_String, _Integer]` or `_Symbol->Subscript[_String, _String]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want something like one of these:

```
StringSplit[{"A1", "AB1", "AB12"}, d : DigitCharacter .. :> d]

StringSplit[{"A1", "AB1", "AB12"}, d__?DigitQ :> d]
```

Both return `{{"A", "1"}, {"AB", "1"}, {"AB", "12"}}`.

[`DigitCharacter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DigitCharacter.html) should be faster as it converts to a regular expression internally whereas `DigitQ` does not:

```
StringPattern`PatternConvert /@ {DigitCharacter .., __?DigitQ} // Column
```

> ```
> {"(?ms)\\d+", {}, {}, Hold[None]}
>
> {"(?ms)(.+)(?C1)", {}, {{Hold[DigitQ], 1}}, Hold[None]}
> ```

Comment: Thanks very much. It is my first time to use the *string function*

Answer (score 3):

Here is a formulation using regular expression groups and POSIX character classes.

```
transformRules = 
  (# -> First @
          StringCases[ToString[#], 
            RegularExpression["([[:alpha:]]+)([[:digit:]]+)"] :> 
              Subscript[Style["$1", Italic], ToExpression["$2"]]] &)

transformRules /@ {A1, AB1, AB12}
```

[image: rules]

The raw input form for the above is

```
{A1 -> Subscript[Style["A", FontSlant -> Italic], 1], 
 AB1 -> Subscript[Style["AB", FontSlant -> Italic], 1], 
 AB12 -> Subscript[Style["AB", FontSlant -> Italic], 12]}
```

Note that the 2nd argument of `Subscript` is an integer and not a string, which appears to be one of your requirements.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution:-)